# Shopping Cart/Billing address logic

Tags: paypal, logic, shopping-cart, payment, billing

As some of you may know (if you read my 24932049023 previous questions :P) I'm working on a shopping site.
The payments will be processed by PayPal and I was wondering if I really need to have my user's Billing Address in that case. It's not like I have to verify their credit cart authenticity...

I know it's not much of a coding question but more of a logic one, I just have no experience in this kind of websites and I don't really know where/who to ask.

Thank you !!

Comment: What PayPal do you use - Standard, Payment Pro, Payflow or Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to store the user's address information.  Just send the user to Paypal, handle the information when they get back, and everything is set.

It really is that easy.